# How to generate a MIDI file from an MP3/WAV file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, mp3, midi

## Disclaimer:

I am NOT trying to perfectly convert a `MP3` to a `MIDI`, as in replicate / identify instruments being used, just stick with one instrument.

I have stumbled across a [site](https://www.conversion-tool.com/audiotomidi/) that somehow disects an audio file and converts it to a `MIDI` file, but the only instrument involved is a piano (which is just fine with me). I tried to replicate it in `NodeJS` using this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/midiconvert and retrieving mp3 data from this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-decode.

I have structured my code like this:

```js
const audioDecode = require('audio-decode');
const midiConvert = require('midiconvert');

                var audioInfo = await audioDecode(bufferFromMP3File);
                /**
                 * @type {Float32Array}
                 */
                var MP3Data = audioInfo._data;
                var newMidi = midiConvert.create();
                var track = newMidi.track().patch(1);
                // I used .map to find 'special' ways on how to iterate through the array quickly, but this probably was not the correct method.
                MP3Data.map((KEY,INDEX) => {
                    track.note(Math.abs(KEY)+12,INDEX,1);
                    //+12 is here because without it, I get an error along the lines of cannot get the index of 1. The KEY variable is a float, or decimal value.
                });
                fs.writeFileSync(file.replace("./input/","./output/"), newMidi.encode(), "binary");
```

This code gives off call stack exceeded errors in the library's code @ `newMidi.encode()`. For larger MP3 files, it flips out and has a memory heap error. How would've the site done it?

The only procedure I can think of is this:

```
Get MP3 Data -> Split it into 1/2 seconds -> Get pitch of each split -> Input it into MIDI
```

AFAIK, `MIDI` is comparable to a `Java` file, where it tells the system what instrument to play at what time compared to java translating itself into code for the system and that telling it what to do. All other questions I found about converting an MP3 to a MIDI file say it is impossible.

Comment: In a few words: it's practically impossible to convert MP3 to MIDI.
One can convert a cow to ground beef, but no one can convert ground beef to a cow.

Comment: +Sema, my problem would be related to how the site does it, instead of worrying about instruments I'm worried about proof-of-concept. You can plug a mp3 through that site and it gives you a `MIDI` that only does piano.

Comment: The website you have mentioned is doing it via some state-of-the-art AI algorithm, most likely using neural network. It is not a one loop map call. Still, acceptable result is not guaranteed.

Comment: +Sema, I just found a solution but its using command line tools in place, I just installed waon & its dependencies.